# I would like to replicate this nested for loop I have in c in an excel vba

Tags: c, excel, vba

Note:I'm aware that this explanation is confusing but when you look at the code I posted it will make a lot more sense. Feel free to suggest any edits.

I'm trying to recreate a a nested for loop I made in c in an excel vba. I need the nested for loop in the excel to function the same way as the  nested for loop in c.

So far I have tried making a nested for loop in excel that is formatted the same as a nested for loop in c (while changing the syntax of course). Currently my excel nested for loop output does not match my c nested for loop output.

Here is my c code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   for (int i=1; i<=2; i++)
   {
    for (int j=1; j<=4; j++)
    {
       printf("%d, %d\n",i ,j);
    }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

And here is the c loop output ( what I'm trying to recreate in excel)

1,1

1,2

1,3

1,4

2,1

2,2

2,3

2,4

And here is my excel code

```
Sub Button2_Click()

For i = 1 To 2
    For j = 1 To 4
        Cells(i, 2).Value = j
        Cells(i, 1).Value = i

    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

And here is the output(I want this output to match the c one)

1,  4

2,  4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a third counter to move down a row each time:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
Dim rw as Long
rw = 1

Dim i as Long
For i = 1 To 2
    Dim j as Long
    For j = 1 To 4
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 2).Value = j
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value = i
        rw = rw + 1    
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I do have a follow up question though. Is it possible to use this code for a bubble sort algorithm in excel?

Comment: New Questions get new posts.